# Can someone suggest or help on creating pytest using mocking open

Tags: python, pyspark, pytest-mock

#pyspark function#

def get_config(env)

```
 if env == 'local':
    with open(f"src/config/config_{env}.yml", "r") as stream:
        try:
            data = yaml.safe_load(stream)
            return data
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print("Error in reading CONFIG file")
else:
       print("Error in reading CONFIG file")
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  I can't follow the question as it currently is

Comment: i have written pyspark function and i need to create pytest function for unit testing

Comment: Maybe [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=textio#io.TextIOWrapper) can help you. You can find some usage examples [here](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/typing/TextIO/-/python-textio-class-examples.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```py
import pytest
from io import StringIO
import yaml


def get_config(env):
    if env == "local":
        with open(f"src/config/config_{env}.yml", "r") as stream:
            try:
                data = yaml.safe_load(stream)
                return data
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print("Error in reading CONFIG file")
    else:
        print("Env is not local")


def test_valid_config(mocker):
    content = "{this: 7}"
    mocked_open = mocker.patch("builtins.open")
    mocked_open.return_value = StringIO(content)
    assert get_config("local") == {"this": 7}
    assert mocked_open.called_once()
```

I leave writing a complete test suite up to you (it'll be tedious, because this function doesn't throw errors but prints to stdout and returns `None` if it fails.

The key think is that you mock builtins with "builtins.thing" (in python 3).

Comment: good :)  Feel free to accept :)

Comment: ??  What does that mean?

Comment: anyhow, if this solved the problem, feel free to accept

Comment: let me add the error part in the problem statement now could you help to provide complete pytest including else part as well. It will be very hepfull

Comment: @premjeetkumar I'm note writing the test suite for you; that's not how this site works.  If you have a specific problem and have tried to solve it I'm happy to help, but I'm not writing your code fo you

Comment: this answer it works for me. so accepting it. Thank you so much.

Comment: I will be creating another post for other doubts :)